# Keycloak OIDC Identity Provider internal server error

Tags: authentication, oauth, keycloak, openid-connect, identity

When I sign into an identity provider I've configured in Keycloak, it redirects me back to Keycloak with a code and state but Keycloak throws a server error instead of accepting the code and creating a token for my application/browser. The server error looks like:

```
Caused by: org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityBrokerException: Wrong audience from token. 
    at org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProvider.validateToken(OIDCIdentityProvider.java:484) 
    at org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProvider.validateToken(OIDCIdentityProvider.java:458) 
    at org.keycloak.broker.oidc.KeycloakOIDCIdentityProvider.processAccessTokenResponse(KeycloakOIDCIdentityProvider.java:67) 
    at org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProvider.extractIdentity(OIDCIdentityProvider.java:425) 
    at org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProvider.getFederatedIdentity(OIDCIdentityProvider.java:351) 
    ... 71 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This particular Keycloak server also had User Federation coming from LDAP, and the users in LDAP were not the same as the ones coming from the identity provider. Moving this Identity Provider to a new realm without LDAP allowed the new users to be created in Keycloak and the session + token to be created.